# One button to affect a table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js, ejs

So, im trying to make a simple page that retrieves and renders a table from mysql table, but I cant understand how I can just use one button to change the table, such as a button that when pressed sends the following query (e.g active orders from a table of orders):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (condition);
```

And then a second button that has this query (e.g completed orders from a table of orders):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (different condition);
```

I'm using handlbars as my templating engine with express and nodejs to handle the rest. Here's what I tried so far:

I tried using routes to affect my table similar to how search works, but without actually searching for anything.

**The Button**

```
<a href="/completed.hbs"> Completed Orders </a>
```

**User.js:**

```
router.get('/completed', userController.complete);
```

**Function I'm trying to call**

```
exports.complete = (req, res) => {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE deleted = 0 AND stat = "Completed"', (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.render('home', { rows });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}
```

**loop to display rows**

```
    {{#each rows}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{this.id}}</th>
      <td>{{this.name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.contact}}</td>
      <td>{{this.address}}</td>
      <td>{{this.food}}</td>
      <td>{{this.stat}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm fairly new to node js and all this backend stuff.

Comment: Nevermind, it started working as soon as I reinstalled all the modules

Comment: please close your question, when you did find a solution. 